# getinfo from Multichain API using JSoup

Tags: java, json, jsoup, blockchain

I am trying to call the method "getInfo" on an existing multichain (that I manage), using the JSoup library to set up the data.

The following method encodes the parameters in JSON:

```
 private static String encode(Map<String, String> params)
    {
        String retval = "";        
        for(Entry<String,String> en : params.entrySet())
        {
            retval += (retval.isEmpty() ? "" : ", ") + "\"" + en.getKey() + "\" : \"" + en.getValue() + "\"";
        }
        retval += ", \"jsonrpc\" : \"1.0\"";
        retval += ", \"params\" : []";
        return "{" + retval + "}";
    }
```

This method then attempts to call the Multichain API that I set up:

```
public static void getBlockChainParams() throws IOException
    {
        // params
        String server = "192.168.00.00"; // obviously not the real IP
        String port = "0000"; // obviously not the real port
        String chainName = "chain1";

        // json
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("method", "getinfo");
        params.put("id", "1");
        params.put("chain_name", chainName);

        String jsonData = encode(params);
        System.out.println(jsonData);

        // build request
        String url = "http://" + server + ":" + port;
        System.out.println(url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)             
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            //.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
            //.header("Accept-Language", "en-EN,es;q=0.8")
            .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
            //.header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .data(jsonData, "")
            .post();

        // send 
       System.out.println(doc.toString());        
    }
```

However, when  I run this code it throws a SocketException.

I tried (roughly) the same code to connect to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and feed it some JSON data, which works perfectly (returning me a bare-bones HTML document containing the data I sent).

Comment: How about that? I have the same problem and I supose it is related with opening connections in multichain. Could you solve it?

Answer (score -2):

DOUBLE QUOTE TO MULTICHAIN SHOULD BE PASSED AS "\